# Angular - Possible to get the newest item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my Angular app I have a comments section.

When a new comment is created I'd like a CSS style to be briefly applied to that new item.

My comments come from a `$scope` array and are displayed using `ng-repeat`.

Is this possible to obtain, the newest item in that array?

Thanks.

Comment: if a comment is added,  say the newest item has a timestamp  attribute , you can use  `ng-repeat = "item in collection | orderBy: 'timestamp'"` make the newest item to be the last one in collection and you got it.

Comment: I'm already using orderBy on another variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last item of your `ng-repeat` will have a scope attribute `$last` set to true. The same way, the first item will have `$first`.

Hence you can do that:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in collection">
  <div ng-class = "{last: $last}">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

The last item will have the class `last` which you can style using CSS.

Comment: Great - thanks for that - do you know if its possible to use this `$last` with `$anchorScroll` - so that it scrolls to this latest item?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about applying a CSS class to the first item why not use the [CSS :first-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)? This could be easily set to a DOM element containing comment items. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bun75ozq/1/):

http://jsfiddle.net/bun75ozq/1/

Controller:

```
$scope.comment = '';
$scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$scope.add = function(){
  if ($scope.comment == '') return;
  $scope.highlightClass = 'container';

  // Add new comment to first position
  $scope.items.splice(0, 0, $scope.comment);
  // Clear
  $scope.comment = '';
};
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="comment" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add comment</button>
</div>
<ul ng-class="highlightClass">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"><span ng-bind="item"></span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.container>li:first-child{
  color: black;

  -webkit-animation:highlight ease-in 1;  
  -moz-animation:highlight ease-in 1;
  animation:highlight ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight { from { color:red; } to { color:black; } }
@-moz-keyframes highlight { from { color:red; } to { color:black; } }
@keyframes highlight { from { color:red; } to { color:black; } }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm using the answer below (`$last` works exactly as I need - as my list is already orders according to another varibale) along with your CSS :-)